# last hour count and last received

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables A and B with the following columns and sample data

Table **A**

```
Id    Code      Name       Active
---------------------------------
1     A1        Apple       t
2     B2        Banana      t
3     C1        Cherry      f
4     D2        Date        t
```

Table **B**

```
Aid             Received     
-----------------------------------
1        2014-10-02 10:24:55.095714
2        2014-10-02 10:54:53.226128
3        2014-10-02 15:39:59.683531
1        2014-10-02 15:39:59.862021
4        2014-10-02 15:42:19.923144
4        2014-10-02 15:49:29.964731
1        2014-10-02 15:53:27.586373
```

`Aid` is the foreign key from table **A**

I need to display the all the names, number each received in the last hour and the last received time

The expected output for the sample data is as follows

```
Name     Count          LastReceived     
-------------------------------------------
Banana     0     2014-10-02 10:54:53.226128
Apple      2     2014-10-02 15:53:27.586373
Date       1     2014-10-02 15:49:29.964731
```

The query I wrote so far is as follows

```
SELECT 
  A.name,
  COUNT(B.Aid) AS Count,
  MAX(B.Received) AS LastReceived
FROM 
  A
FULL OUTER JOIN
  B
ON A.id = B.Aid 
WHERE B.Received > (NOW() - INTERVAL '1 hour') AND A.Active = TRUE --approx. 3pm to 4pm 10/2/2014
GROUP BY A.name
ORDER BY Count, A.name
```

I am not getting the expected output with this query. How should I modify the query to get the expected output ?

**EDIT**

I need to order the result with the ones with zero count displaying first alphabetically and then the rest alphabetically. Can I do this in a single query? I know adding  `ORDER BY Count, A.name` won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble you have is the where clause excludes rows you want to consider for the last received date. One way to work around it is with conditional aggregation:

```
select
  a.name,
  sum(case when b.Received > (now() - interval '1 hour') then 1 else 0 end) AS Count,
  max(b.Received) as LastReceived
from
  a
    left outer join
  b
    on a.id = b.aid 
where
  a.Active = true
group by
  a.name
order by
  case when sum(case when b.Received > (now() - interval '1 hour') then 1 else 0 end) = 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  a.name
```

The way the order by works might be easier to understand by pulling out a common table expression:

```
with x as (
  select
    a.name,
    sum(case when b.Received > '2014-10-02 15:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) AS Count,
    max(b.Received) as LastReceived
  from
    a
      left outer join
    b
      on a.id = b.aid 
  where
    a.Active = true
  group by
    a.name
) select
  x.name,
  x.count,
  x.lastreceived
from
  x
order by
  case when x.Count = 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  x.name
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06aad/8)

Comment: I edited the question. Can you modify the answer to incorporate the ordering mentioned?

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can you please explain what you did with the outer `CASE WHEN`?

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the example. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct, except you need a `LEFT JOIN`, as table `A` is your driving relations:

```
SELECT a.name,
       count(b.aid),
       max(b.received) AS LastReceived
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.aid AND b.received > now()-INTERVAL '1 hour'
 WHERE a.active
 GROUP BY a.name
 ORDER BY a.name;
```

Also, it is important whether you're filtering out results in the `WHERE` clause which, in your case, skips all entries that could possibly yield zero counts, or you put filter in the join conditions (like above).

Comment: Thanks. I don't get the LastReceived timestamp for items with zero count

Comment: @Srikanth: Hm, what is the meaning of the `LastReceived`, if nothing had been received within the specified interval?

Comment: In table B there were no bananas received in the last hour ( approx. 3pm to 4pm 10/2/2014) so the count will be zero but last received banana was at around 11am on 10/2/2014 so that time should be displayed

Comment: @Srikanth, I see. Laurence's answer is the you should go with then.